# Generate data for dates based on a constraint

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df1 having  column for date_1 with values from 01/09/2019 to 30/09/2019. i.e. 30 values and respective count.

**DF1**

```
    date_1    count
    01/09/2019  5
    02/09/2019  4
    03/09/2019  5
    04/09/2019  6
    05/09/2019  7
    06/09/2019  8
    07/09/2019  10
    08/09/2019  9
    09/09/2019  11
    10/09/2019  12
    11/09/2019  13
    12/09/2019  14
    13/09/2019  15
    14/09/2019  16
```

I want to generate a dataframe df2 such that :

1. There is a new column date_2.
2. date_2 are generated on the feature of the count present in df1.

For example: a new dataframe df2 has 5 entries(since count = 5) for 01/09/2019 and date_2 column can take values from 30 days before date_1 to 30/08/2019(current date in date_1 - 1)

**Expected Output :**

```
    date_1    count   date_2
    01/09/2019  5     02/08/2019
    01/09/2019  5     10/08/2019
    01/09/2019  5     12/08/2019
    01/09/2019  5     25/08/2019
    01/09/2019  5     28/08/2019
    02/09/2019  4     03/08/2019
    02/09/2019  4     10/08/2019
    02/09/2019  4     20/08/2019
    02/09/2019  4     25/08/2019
```

date_2 can be randomly selected from the range (`30 - date_1` to `date_1 - 1`) i.e. in our example for 01/09/2019, from 02/08/2019 to 30/08/2019

**EDIT**

I was able to generate random date_2 using the function :

```
def pick_random_delta_in_range(min_days=1, max_days=30):
    if min_days is None and max_days is None:
        return datetime.timedelta(days=1, minutes=0, seconds=0)
    if min_days is None:
        return max_days
    if max_days is None:
        return min_days
    days_to_be_added = random.randint(min_days, max_days)
    return datetime.timedelta(days=days_to_be_added, minutes=0, seconds=0)

def gen_date_by_delta(src_dates, date_format, delta_min, delta_max):
    gen_dates = []
    for dt in src_dates:
        src_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, date_format)

        if src_date is None:
            gen_dates.append("")
            continue

        chosen_delta = pick_random_delta_in_range(min_days=delta_min, max_days=delta_max)

        result_date = (src_date + chosen_delta).strftime(date_format)
        gen_dates.append(result_date)

    return gen_dates

date_2 = gen_date_by_delta(src_dates=df1["date_1"], date_format=date_format, delta_min=1, delta_max=30)
```

I am not able to understand how to replicate the fields in the dataframe according to the count and generate the dates accordingly.

***Currently the delta is generated randomly and might generate the same delta for the same date_1 resulting in the duplicate entries. I don't want to generate the duplicate entries. ***

Can anyone suggest a way to generate the same.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? @vp7

Comment: @Vishnudev I was able to generate a random range  based on generating a random delta from 1-30 and generating the date_2 based on that, but I am not able to understand how to replicate the values based on the count.

Comment: @Vishnudev I have edited the question with the function that I wrote for generating the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you can create a customized function that returns random date in specified format between `date-30` and `date-1` and apply this function to repeated dates of your new Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

def get_randomized_str_date(input_str_date):
    ub_date = pd.to_datetime(input_str_date, dayfirst=True) - pd.DateOffset(1)
    lb_date = ub_date - pd.DateOffset(29)
    dates_range = pd.date_range(lb_date, ub_date)
    return random.choice(dates_range).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

# Create sample DataFrame
data = {'date_1': ['01/09/2019', '02/09/2019', '03/09/2019'],
        'count': [5, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
#        date_1  count
# 0  01/09/2019      5
# 1  02/09/2019      4
# 2  03/09/2019      5

# Preprocess created DataFrame
df_new = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['count'])] # repeat each row n-times, where n stored in df['count']
df_new['date_2'] = df_new['date_1'].apply(lambda x: get_randomized_str_date(x)) # get random date for specified date
print(df_new)
#        date_1  count      date_2
# 0  01/09/2019      5  18/08/2019
# 0  01/09/2019      5  23/08/2019
# 0  01/09/2019      5  23/08/2019
# 0  01/09/2019      5  27/08/2019
# 0  01/09/2019      5  12/08/2019
# 1  02/09/2019      4  11/08/2019
# 1  02/09/2019      4  02/08/2019
# 1  02/09/2019      4  03/08/2019
# 1  02/09/2019      4  23/08/2019
# 2  03/09/2019      5  01/09/2019
# 2  03/09/2019      5  28/08/2019
# 2  03/09/2019      5  21/08/2019
# 2  03/09/2019      5  19/08/2019
# 2  03/09/2019      5  31/08/2019
```

**UPDATE**

To avoid duplicate dates in date_2 column you can do following:

For each unique date in date_1 column you can create a generator of dates that satisfy your requirements and for each appearence of date from date_1 column you can yield a unique date from generator that coresponds to that date:

```
def get_date_generator(input_str_date):
    ub_date = pd.to_datetime(input_str_date, dayfirst=True) - pd.DateOffset(1)
    lb_date = ub_date - pd.DateOffset(29)
    dates_range = [date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') for date in pd.date_range(lb_date, ub_date)]
    np.random.shuffle(dates_range)
    return (date for date in dates_range)

def process_date_iter(generator):
    try:
        next_date = generator.__next__()
    except StopIteration:
        next_date = np.nan
    return next_date

dates_generators = {date: get_date_generator(date) for date in df['date_1'].unique()}
df_new = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['count'])]
df_new['date_2'] = df_new['date_1'].apply(lambda x: process_date_iter(dates_generators[x]))
print(df_new)
#        date_1  count      date_2
# 0  01/09/2019      5  04/08/2019
# 0  01/09/2019      5  14/08/2019
# 0  01/09/2019      5  25/08/2019
# 0  01/09/2019      5  03/08/2019
# 0  01/09/2019      5  02/08/2019
# 1  02/09/2019      4  14/08/2019
# 1  02/09/2019      4  08/08/2019
# 1  02/09/2019      4  30/08/2019
# 1  02/09/2019      4  28/08/2019
# 2  03/09/2019      5  29/08/2019
# 2  03/09/2019      5  10/08/2019
# 2  03/09/2019      5  26/08/2019
# 2  03/09/2019      5  15/08/2019
# 2  03/09/2019      5  28/08/2019
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want a random date in date_2. date_2 should be generated between the range (date_1 - 30) days to (date_1 -1) days. and the entries should not be repeated as well. Can you please edit your answer according to that?

Comment: The value generated in your result are not correct for date_2. if you see that, for 01/09/2019 date_2 generated is 11/12/2018 which is not correct

Comment: Hello @vp7! Make changes to correct dates preprocessing. Need a time, to think about how to create non-repeatable random dates for each date.

Comment: @vp7, you can see an update section of how to avoid duplicates in date_2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reindex` to repeat the rows,

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['count'])).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Results in

```
         date_1  count
0    01/09/2019      5
1    01/09/2019      5
2    01/09/2019      5
3    01/09/2019      5
4    01/09/2019      5
..          ...    ...
130  14/09/2019     16
131  14/09/2019     16
132  14/09/2019     16
133  14/09/2019     16
134  14/09/2019     16
```

For continuous, non-repetitive range of dates,

```
>>> df['date_2'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['date_1'], periods=x['count']).to_list(), axis=1)
>>> df = df.explode('date_2')
>>> df
        date_1  count     date_2
0   01/09/2019      5 2019-01-09
0   01/09/2019      5 2019-01-10
0   01/09/2019      5 2019-01-11
0   01/09/2019      5 2019-01-12
0   01/09/2019      5 2019-01-13
..         ...    ...        ...
13  14/09/2019     16 2019-09-25
13  14/09/2019     16 2019-09-26
13  14/09/2019     16 2019-09-27
13  14/09/2019     16 2019-09-28
13  14/09/2019     16 2019-09-29

[135 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I do this as the first step and then apply my function to generate the date_2, is that what you are implying by this ?

Comment: One more doubt regarding the same, if I generate from my function, it is randomly generating the delta, there is a possibility of repeated delta for the same date, How can I tackle the same in my function ?

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for... it is printing the dates continuously. I was hoping for randomized date_2 from date_1-30 to date_1-1 days. Your answer just prints the dates according to the counts. I have mentioned the same in the question. Can you please check that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is an alternative (more basic) to the previous answer to expand the first column:

```
df_new=pd.DataFrame() 

l=[]
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    for j in range(df.loc[i,'count']):
        l.append(r.date_1)

df_new.date_1=l
print(df_new)
```

then you could use **.apply** and your functions to define the new column...